# JSQMessengerViewController issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have installed JSQMessenger View Controller in my existing project. When I pass it to a view controller as a class it shows no error but when I tried to import the JSQMessengerViewController in my class file it shows that file not found. I don't know why it is showing such issue. While my pods are installed correctly. These are some errors.
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/Documentation/getting_started.md

Comment: Are you open .xcworkspace after installing the pod?

Comment: yes i have opened my project i .xcworkspace. @HaroldoGondim

Comment: Try to clean the project and build again

Comment: Bro done all the things , but not working :( . @HaroldoGondim

Comment: Followed these all the stuff but still stuck here. @Moritz

Comment: i have used bridging in my project , but when i import file in swift it shows issue in swift class . It is imported in Objective c fine. @HaroldoGondim

Comment: False problem, man. If it's imported in the bridging header, this is all you have to do. No need to add an import line in the Swift part. Try just removing it. :)

Comment: i didn't get it? suppose i have a view controller and i have given it a class JSQMessengerViewController  now i have to import the JSQMessengerViewController still? @Moritz

Comment: No. You already have imported JSQMessengerViewController in the bridging header, and the bridging header brings it to your Swift code. Just try...

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering with the same issue a while ago. I just deintegrate pod with

> pod deintegrate

and,then install pod with

> pod install

.and then not run .xcworkspace directly. just build project for one time and then run. It solved my problem.

Comment: what it means that not run .xcworkspace than how u buld the project. @Abhi Makadia

Comment: I mean open .xcodeworkspace and press cmd+B to build Project.and after that run Project with cmd+R.